# Setting fixed width for parent table

Tags: html, css

I have read around css properties for tables but I fail to understand why I cannot set a fixed width for my parent table: it always gets overridden by css properties further downstream. e.g. my code below:

Any idea how I can set the table to width 200, and then get the text to wrap in the nested table? Right now all tables are stretching to accommodate lengthy text :-(

http://jsfiddle.net/8weav9qo/

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" width="200">
        <tr width="100px">
            <td>
          Title<br/><br/>                         
          <table cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0"><tr>
            <td><img src="http://www.macaulay.ac.uk/IFRU/images/blue_arrow.gif"></img></td>        
            <td>HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello</td>
          </tr></table>
          <table cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0"><tr>
            <td><img src="http://www.macaulay.ac.uk/IFRU/images/blue_arrow.gif"></img></td>        
            <td>Hello</td>
          </tr></table>
          <table cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0"><tr>
            <td><img src="http://www.macaulay.ac.uk/IFRU/images/blue_arrow.gif"></img></td>        
            <td>Hello</td>
          </tr></table>            
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use divs instead of tables?, it will be easier to manipulate and better cross browser behavior.

Comment: `tr` doesn't have a `width` attribute.

Comment: You can try `td {word-break: break-all;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `table-layout: fixed` - http://jsfiddle.net/8weav9qo/2/